# Good practice for Java entity classes and its unit tests

Tags: java

I just want to confirm if you guys think it is a good practice:

- To write entity classes in java with some validations with javax.validation.constraints annotations
- To write unit test to assert that validations
- To write unit test to assert the getters and setters as it is a way to assert that the class contains all fields we need

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(exclude = "client")
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "addresses")
public class Address extends BaseEntity {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -5966581124342250987L;

  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 2, max = 40)
  @Column(name = "line1", nullable = false, length = 40)
  private String line1;

  @Size(min = 2, max = 40)
  @Column(name = "line2", length = 40)
  private String line2;

  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 2, max = 40)
  @Column(name = "city", length = 40)
  private String city;

  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 2, max = 2)
  @Column(name = "country_code", length = 2)
  private String countryCode; //code ISO 3166 two-letter country codes

  @NotNull
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
  private Client client;

}
```

```
class AddressTest {

  private static final String ADDRESS_LINE1 = "Address line 1";
  private static final String ADDRESS_LINE2 = "Address line 2";
  private static final String ADDRESS_CITY = "Address City";
  private static final String ADDRESS_COUNTRY_CODE = "IT";
  private static final Client ADDRESS_CLIENT = new Client();

  private Address address;

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    address = Address.builder()
            .line1( ADDRESS_LINE1 )
            .line2( ADDRESS_LINE2 )
            .city( ADDRESS_CITY )
            .countryCode( ADDRESS_COUNTRY_CODE )
            .client( ADDRESS_CLIENT )
            .build();
  }

  @Test
  public void CreateAddress_AssertBasicFields() {
    assertEquals(ADDRESS_LINE1, address.getLine1());

    assertEquals(ADDRESS_LINE2, address.getLine2());

    assertEquals(ADDRESS_CITY, address.getCity());

    assertEquals(ADDRESS_COUNTRY_CODE, address.getCountryCode());
  }

  @Test
  public void CreateAddress_AssertClient() {
    assertEquals(ADDRESS_CLIENT, address.getClient());
  }
}
```

```
public class AddressValidationTest {
  private static ValidatorFactory validatorFactory;
  private static Validator validator;

  private static final String ADDRESS_LINE1 = "Address line 1";
  private static final String ADDRESS_LINE2 = "Address line 2";
  private static final String ADDRESS_CITY = "Address City";
  private static final String ADDRESS_COUNTRY_CODE = "IT";
  private static final Client ADDRESS_CLIENT = new Client();

  @BeforeAll
  public static void createValidator() {
    validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();
  }

  @AfterAll
  public static void close() {
    validatorFactory.close();
  }

  @Test
  public void shouldHaveNoViolations() {
    //given:
    Address address = Address.builder()
            .line1( ADDRESS_LINE1 )
            .line2( ADDRESS_LINE2 )
            .city( ADDRESS_CITY )
            .countryCode( ADDRESS_COUNTRY_CODE )
            .client( ADDRESS_CLIENT )
            .build();

    //when:
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Address>> violations
            = validator.validate(address);

    //then:
    assertTrue(violations.isEmpty());
  }

  @Test
  public void shouldDetectInvalidLine1() {
    //given too short name:
    Address address = Address.builder()
            .line1( "L" )
            .line2( ADDRESS_LINE2 )
            .city( ADDRESS_CITY )
            .countryCode( ADDRESS_COUNTRY_CODE )
            .client( ADDRESS_CLIENT )
            .build();

    //when:
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Address>> violations = validator.validate(address);

    //then:
    assertEquals(1, violations.size());

    ConstraintViolation<Address> violation = violations.iterator().next();
    assertEquals("size must be between 2 and 40", violation.getMessage());
    assertEquals("line1", violation.getPropertyPath().toString());
    assertEquals("L", violation.getInvalidValue());
  }

  @Test
  public void shouldDetectInvalidLine2() {
    //given too short name:
    Address address = Address.builder()
            .line1( ADDRESS_LINE1 )
            .line2( "L" )
            .city( ADDRESS_CITY )
            .countryCode( ADDRESS_COUNTRY_CODE )
            .client( ADDRESS_CLIENT )
            .build();

    //when:
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Address>> violations = validator.validate(address);

    //then:
    assertEquals(1, violations.size());

    ConstraintViolation<Address> violation = violations.iterator().next();
    assertEquals("size must be between 2 and 40", violation.getMessage());
    assertEquals("line2", violation.getPropertyPath().toString());
    assertEquals("L", violation.getInvalidValue());
  }

  @Test
  public void shouldDetectInvalidCity() {
    //given too short name:
    Address address = Address.builder()
            .line1( ADDRESS_LINE1 )
            .line2( ADDRESS_LINE2 )
            .city( "Aaaaaaaaaa AAAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBBBBBb dddddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeeeee ffffffffffff ggggggggggg" )
            .countryCode( ADDRESS_COUNTRY_CODE )
            .client( ADDRESS_CLIENT )
            .build();

    //when:
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Address>> violations = validator.validate(address);

    //then:
    assertEquals( 1, violations.size());

    ConstraintViolation<Address> violation = violations.iterator().next();
    assertEquals("size must be between 2 and 40", violation.getMessage());
    assertEquals("city", violation.getPropertyPath().toString());
    assertEquals("Aaaaaaaaaa AAAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBBBBBb dddddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeeeee ffffffffffff ggggggggggg", violation.getInvalidValue());
  }

  @Test
  public void shouldDetectInvalidCountryCode() {
    //given too short name:
    Address address = Address.builder()
            .line1( ADDRESS_LINE1 )
            .line2( ADDRESS_LINE2 )
            .city( ADDRESS_CITY )
            .countryCode( "ITA" )
            .client( ADDRESS_CLIENT )
            .build();

    //when:
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Address>> violations = validator.validate(address);

    //then:
    assertEquals( 1, violations.size());

    ConstraintViolation<Address> violation = violations.iterator().next();
    assertEquals("size must be between 2 and 2", violation.getMessage());
    assertEquals("countryCode", violation.getPropertyPath().toString());
    assertEquals("ITA", violation.getInvalidValue());
  }

  @Test
  public void shouldDetectInvalidClient() {
    //given too short name:
    Address address = Address.builder()
            .line1( ADDRESS_LINE1 )
            .line2( ADDRESS_LINE2 )
            .city( ADDRESS_CITY )
            .countryCode( ADDRESS_COUNTRY_CODE )
            .build();

    //when:
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Address>> violations = validator.validate(address);

    //then:
    assertEquals( 1, violations.size());

    ConstraintViolation<Address> violation = violations.iterator().next();
    assertEquals("must not be null", violation.getMessage());
    assertEquals("client", violation.getPropertyPath().toString());
    assertEquals(null, violation.getInvalidValue());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that actually you test only a small part of what you use : for example all and no arg constructors, setter, `hashCode()` and `equals()` are not tested.

Now is it a good practice to test that ? 
I think that it is.
Using Lombok annotations generates some implementations which you can verify the behavior only at runtime (test and application runtime).
For example an annotation may not produce the expected behavior because in conflict with another one or because incorrectly used (an stackoverflow error if a cycle exists in a generated method for example) and you may discover these only at runtime with at best an exception stating clearly the issue or at worst a insidious bug which the root cause is not obvious.
Similarly, if someone breaks inadvertently the implementation by replacing it (for debugging purpose) :

```
@ToString(exclude = "client")
```

by :

```
@ToString
```

you want that an automated test detects it.
At last, if you want to remove Lombok of your project for any reason, you would like to have regression tests that can assert that the new implementation without Lombok is still correct.
So yes using many annotations mean write many assertions/tests.
But in a some way that is normal as powering your classes by third-party API is not a detail.
Note that for getters/setters I don't think that it brings a great value to test them since the fact of being able to invoke them generally mean that these were correctly implemented by Lombok.

Reasoning in these terms (unitary testing what your class API provides) favors the production of helpful and quality code because we will think twice before adding an annotation that generates some code/logic. And that is a good thing because, I often see abuse of  Lombok annotations : "we are not sure to need that but no problem as that is easy to be declared".

I would apply exactly the same idea for  `javax.validation.constraints` annotations while for validation matter, I would probably use parameterized tests to reduce boiler plate code.

Answer (score 0):

Entitys are the augmented-mirror of a database (the instance is the SSOT, the class is the SVOT), the M im MVC, they are beans. Should beans be unit-tested: No.

What you do is you mix the M and the C in the entitys. Should the C be unit-tested? `Yes!!!`.

**So you really should test them!**

Answer (score 0):

Entities are just POJO objects without logic. It's worth to know what exactly you test.

If you want to test entity validators it's worth to put some random data instead of predefined

not `private static final String ADDRESS_LINE1 = "Address line 1";` but

```
 Address address = Address.builder()
            .line1( randomAddress() )
            .city( randomCity() )
            .countryCode( randomCountry() )
            .build()
```

where `random*()` are predefined methods which return some valid return values.

If you want to test Hibernate and mappers, It's worth to consider some embedded database like [H2](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-test-in-memory-database) to make tests.

Regarding getters and setters, most time they are automatically generated, that's why I don't see a point to test them.